# What is the proper way to use methods that return an enumerator in Ruby array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coding-style

Many methods in [Ruby array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html) return an enumerator when invoked without parameters or blocks (`index`, `keep_if`, `each`, `drop_while` and many more).

- When is it appropriate to use methods in this form, as opposed to calling them with a block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs to [`Enumerator`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html):

> Most methods have two forms: a block form where the contents are
>   evaluated for each item in the enumeration, and a non-block form which
>   returns a new Enumerator wrapping the iteration.
>
> This allows you to chain Enumerators together. For example, you can
>   map a list’s elements to strings containing the index and the element
>   as a string via:
>
> ```
> puts %w[foo bar baz].map.with_index {|w,i| "#{i}:#{w}" }
> # => ["0:foo", "1:bar", "2:baz"]
> ```
>
> An Enumerator can also be used as an external iterator. For example,
>   Enumerator#next returns the next value of the iterator or raises
>   StopIteration if the Enumerator is at the end.
>
> ```
> e = [1,2,3].each   # returns an enumerator object.
> puts e.next   # => 1
> puts e.next   # => 2
> puts e.next   # => 3
> puts e.next   # raises StopIteration
> ```

I'm sorry for copy-paste, but I couldn't explain better.

Answer (score 3):

The main original reason for the Enumerator class to exist is method chaining:

```
array.each.with_object [[], []] { |element, memo| ... }
```

So basically, you don't need to worry about that.